# How to prove that estimator is plug-in estimator?

Tags: statistics

I need to prove that:

a) sample median is a plug-in estimator

b) sample quantile is a plug-in estimator,

but I have no idea where to start;

In a) :

$$M = 
  \begin{cases}
   X_{\left(\frac{n+1}{2}:n\right)} & \text{if } n \text{ is odd} \\[6pt]
   \frac{X_{\left(\frac{n}{2}:n\right)} + X_{\left(\frac{n}{2}+1:n\right)} }{2}      & \text{if } n \text{ is even}
  \end{cases} $$

but I don't know how to connect this with empirical CDF